# Delete the last part of a string SQL

Tags: sql, string, function

I have a field named Path and it looks like this:

```
/{e8cfdcba-9572-4c64-828f-dea54d8a00b7}/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena/GroupingEx.rdl
```

I need a parameter from where i can choose a folder name. Something like this:

```
/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena
```

What i have done by now is to delete the first bit of the path. This is the code:

```
SELECT replace(reverse(substring(reverse(Path), 1, ISNULL(NullIF(charindex('}',reverse(Path)),0),len(Path))) ),'}','') AS Path2 from Catalog
```

Now, my path looks like this: `/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena/GroupingEx.rdl`

How can i exclude the report's name? (for example GroupingEx.rdl). I tried the MID function, but it doesn't work because the report's name length is variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the methods

```
declare @s varchar(200)
set @s='/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena/GroupingEx.rdl'
select reverse(replace(reverse(@s),substring(reverse(@s),1,charindex('/',reverse(@s))),''))
```

EDIT:

This is much simpler

```
declare @s varchar(200)
set @s='/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena/GroupingEx.rdl'
select substring(@s,1,len(@s)-charindex('/',reverse(@s)))
```

Comment: Interesting indeed +1

Comment: Thanks @PKirby for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this function:

```
SUBSTRING([path], CHARINDEX('/', [path], 2), 
          LEN([path]) - CHARINDEX('/', [path], 2) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE([path]), 1) + 1)
```

for this: `/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @str varchar(250)
set @str = '/{e8cfdcba-9572-4c64-828f-dea54d8a00b7}/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena/GroupingEx.rdl'
select substring ( 
        @str, --expression
        charindex('}', @str) + 1, --start
        len(@str) - charindex('/', reverse(@str)) - charindex('}', @str) --how many characters of the expression will be returned
    )
```

OutPut:

```
/sites/BI_Center/euroreporting/Reports/BITraining/Elena
```